# New Zealand Refugee Travel Document

Tags: china, new-zealand, refugees

Does Chinese Customs Service allow people to enter China with a valid Chinese tourist visa ( visitor visa ) on a Refugee Travel Document issued by New Zealand Government?

Comment: Just to make things clear, you need to avoid deportation to Russia?! Does Russia have some type of search warrant on you? And have you tried contacting the Kiwi embassy in China (maybe also the consulate in SH) with your questions? They should be able to help.

Comment: Oh no. I am pretty sure that Russia has no search warrant on me. What I am saying is, Refugee Travel Document might look suspicious, as I said, I was born in China and grew up in Russia, recently moved to New Zealand and got my refugee status here.